# Getting NameError: name 'count_even' is not defined , when trying to get the odd and even numbers of a number set

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the even and odd numbers of a set but for some reason I am getting the error;
NameError: name 'count_even' is not defined , what could the issue be?

```
count_odd=0
for select in [321,13,42,9785,20,33,834,903,22]:
    if select % 2 == 0:
       count_even=count_even + 1
    else:
        count_odd=  count_odd + 1
print(count_even)
print( count_odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error you get is obvious and self-explanatory. you didn't define count even in global scope that why you get the error. 
below `count_odd` you need to define `count_even`

this is whole code

```py
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
for select in [321, 13, 42, 9785, 20, 33, 834, 903, 22]:
    if select % 2 == 0:
        count_even = count_even + 1
    else:
        count_odd = count_odd + 1
print(count_even)
print(count_odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is always on the error statement. You didn't specify `count_even` before using it in line 4

```py
count_odd=0
count_even=0
for select in [321,13,42,9785,20,33,834,903,22]:
    if select % 2 == 0:
        count_even=count_even + 1
    else:
        count_odd=  count_odd + 1
print(count_even)
print( count_odd)
```